# Integrating javascript into the body code of DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I need the help of a Javascript expert.

I can't seem to be able how to figure as to how to integrate the code below into the DOM once the function write_it() is executed. This code allows a user to click on a row and have it highlighted.

Here is the code that needs to be inserted into the code below (somehow):

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
(function() {
var color = "#E1E0D7"
var rows = document.getElementById("mstrTable").getElementsByTagName("tr");
var n = rows.length;
var bgcs = [];
for(var i=0; i<n; ++i) bgcs[i] = rows[i].style.backgroundColor;
//rows[0].style.backgroundColor = color;
function changeColor(e) {
if(!e) e = window.event;
var o = e.target? e.target: e.srcElement;
while(o.tagName && o.tagName.toLowerCase()!="tr") o = o.parentNode;
for(var i=0; i<n; ++i) {
rows[i].style.backgroundColor = bgcs[i];
if(rows[i]==o) rows[i].style.backgroundColor = color;
}
}
if(document.addEventListener) for(var i=0; i<n; ++i) rows[i].addEventListener("click", changeColor, false);
else for(var i=0; i<n; ++i) rows[i].attachEvent("onclick", changeColor);
})();
</script>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Scrolling Data Grid</title>
<style>
/* ==================================================================== */
/* SCROLLING DATA GRID - IE ONLY!                                       */
/* ==================================================================== */
/* 
Tables inside a scrollingdatagrid should have:
 1. border-collapse:separate
 2. No border or margin
 3. Background colors on all cells to avoid bleed-thru on scroll
 4. cellspacing="0" on the <table> tag itself
*/
DIV.scrollingdatagrid {
    overflow-x:auto;
    overflow-y:auto;
    position:relative;
    padding:0px;
}
DIV.scrollingdatagrid TABLE {
    width : 98.7%; /* Make room for scroll bar! */
    margin:0px;
    border:0px;
    border-collapse:separate;
}
DIV.scrollingdatagrid TABLE TR .locked, DIV.scrollingdatagrid TABLE THEAD TR, DIV.scrollingdatagrid TABLE TFOOT TR {
    position:relative;
}
/* OffsetParent of the TR is the DIV because it is position:relative */
DIV.scrollingdatagrid TABLE THEAD TR {
    top:expression(this.offsetParent.scrollTop);
}


/* Make the z-index values very clear so overlaps happen as expected! */
DIV.scrollingdatagrid TD, DIV.scrollingdatagrid TH { z-index:1; }
DIV.scrollingdatagrid TD.locked, DIV.scrollingdatagrid TH.locked { z-index:2; }
DIV.scrollingdatagrid THEAD TR, DIV.scrollingdatagrid TFOOT TR { z-index:3; }
DIV.scrollingdatagrid THEAD TR TH.locked { z-index:4; }
</style>


<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){ write_it() }

function write_it() {

var cn      =   new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection")
var rs      =   new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset")
var dbFile  =   "imts.mdb"
var dbPath  =   "G:\\AS\\Asf\\ASF\\IMTS\\V8\\database\\"

var mySQL   = "SELECT * FROM tbl_imts WHERE [FILE NUMBER] LIKE '%99%'"
var html    = ""

cn.Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = " + dbPath + dbFile + "");
rs.Open(mySQL, cn, 1, 3)

html += '<table id="mstrTable" style="table-layout: fixed; font-family: arial; font-size: 9pt;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">\n'
html += '<thead>\n'
html += '<tr>\n'
html += '<th class="locked" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; border-left: 1px solid #ffffff; border-right: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); text-align: center; height: 30px; width: 20px; color: rgb(102,102,102); background-color: rgb(212,208,200);">#</th>\n'
html += '<th style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; border-left: 1px solid #ffffff; border-right: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); padding-left: 5px; width: 110px; color: rgb(102,102,102); background-color: rgb(212,208,200);">' + rs.fields(0).name + '</th>\n'
html += '<th style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; border-left: 1px solid #ffffff; border-right: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); padding-left: 5px; width: 110px; color: rgb(102,102,102); background-color: rgb(212,208,200);">' + rs.fields(1).name + '</th>\n'
html += '<th style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; border-left: 1px solid #ffffff; border-right: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); padding-left: 5px; width: 110px; color: rgb(102,102,102); background-color: rgb(212,208,200);">' + rs.fields(2).name + '</th>\n'
html += '<th style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; border-left: 1px solid #ffffff; border-right: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); padding-left: 5px; width: 110px; color: rgb(102,102,102); background-color: rgb(212,208,200);">' + rs.fields(3).name + '</th>\n'
html += '<th style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; border-left: 1px solid #ffffff; border-right: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); padding-left: 5px; width: 110px; color: rgb(102,102,102); background-color: rgb(212,208,200);">' + rs.fields(4).name + '</th>\n'
html += '<th style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; border-left: 1px solid #ffffff; border-right: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); padding-left: 5px; width: 110px; color: rgb(102,102,102); background-color: rgb(212,208,200);">' + rs.fields(5).name + '</th>\n'
html += '<th style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; border-left: 1px solid #ffffff; border-right: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); padding-left: 5px; width: 110px; color: rgb(102,102,102); background-color: rgb(212,208,200);">' + rs.fields(6).name + '</th>\n'
html += '<th style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; border-left: 1px solid #ffffff; border-right: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); padding-left: 5px; width: 110px; color: rgb(102,102,102); background-color: rgb(212,208,200);">' + rs.fields(7).name + '</th>\n'
html += '<th style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; border-left: 1px solid #ffffff; border-right: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); padding-left: 5px; width: 110px; color: rgb(102,102,102); background-color: rgb(212,208,200);">' + rs.fields(8).name + '</th>\n'
html += '<th style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; border-left: 1px solid #ffffff; border-right: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); padding-left: 5px; width: 110px; color: rgb(102,102,102); background-color: rgb(212,208,200);">' + rs.fields(9).name + '</th>\n'
html += '<th style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; border-left: 1px solid #ffffff; border-right: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); padding-left: 5px; width: 110px; color: rgb(102,102,102); background-color: rgb(212,208,200);">' + rs.fields(10).name + '</th>\n'
html += '<th style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; border-left: 1px solid #ffffff; border-right: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); padding-left: 5px; width: 110px; color: rgb(102,102,102); background-color: rgb(212,208,200);">' + rs.fields(11).name + '</th>\n'
html += '<th style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; border-left: 1px solid #ffffff; border-right: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); padding-left: 5px; width: 110px; color: rgb(102,102,102); background-color: rgb(212,208,200);">' + rs.fields(12).name + '</th>\n'
html += '<th style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; border-left: 1px solid #ffffff; border-right: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); padding-left: 5px; width: 110px; color: rgb(102,102,102); background-color: rgb(212,208,200);">' + rs.fields(13).name + '</th>\n'
html += '<th style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; border-left: 1px solid #ffffff; border-right: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); padding-left: 5px; width: 110px; color: rgb(102,102,102); background-color: rgb(212,208,200);">' + rs.fields(14).name + '</th>\n'
html += '<th style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; border-left: 1px solid #ffffff; border-right: none; padding-left: 5px; width: 100px; color: rgb(102,102,102); background-color: rgb(212,208,200);">' + rs.fields(15).name + '</th>\n'
html += '</tr>\n'
html += '</thead>\n'

rs.MoveFirst
var i = 0
html += '<tbody>\n'
while (!rs.eof) {
++i
html += '<tr style="color: rgb(102,102,102)">\n'
html += '<td class="locked" style="height: 20px; text-align: center; border-right: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128);">'+i+'.</td>\n'
    for (var r = 0; r < rs.fields.count; ++r) {
    if (!rs.fields(r).value) { rs.fields(r).value = "&nbsp;" }
    html    +=  '<td style="border-right: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128); padding-left: 5px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;">'+rs.fields(r).value+'</td>\n'
    }//end of for
    html    +=  '</tr>\n'
    rs.MoveNext 
    }//end of while
html += '</tbody>\n'
html += '</table>\n'

document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = html
}



</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should start by moving the top `<script>` block into the `<head>` part of your HTML document.

Then, after you do that, try describing in greater detail what part of the code you supplied you want to get into the DOM.

Perhaps you could try to describe what you have tried and why you think it did not work...